# Is it possible to direct linux timer notification signal to a specific thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, timer, posix

I want to implement a timer handling module in my system using Linux POSIX timers API.
A user can start a timer, and give a callback.
Invocation of the callback will be done from a thread (and not from the signal handler).

I was thinking of setting timer_create() with SIGEV_SIGNAL, and the thread waiting for signals using sigwaitinfo(), (the signal arg will give the timerId which will invoke the required callback)

How does the signals are routed in the linux kernel? do I need to specify to which thread they are sent?

Comment: Did you look into [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and the Linux-specific [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) & [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a signal can be delivered to any thread, and you shouldn't make assumptions to which one. Posix threads, however, give you some control over this. You will normally use SIGALRM in conjunction with timer, but I have an example with SIGHUP, so I will show it here to demonstrate the workflow.

When your application starts the main thread sets global disposition of the signal to be ignored:

```
int    n;
sigset_t    set;    
struct sigaction disp;

bzero(&disp, sizeof(disp));
disp.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
if (sigaction(SIGHUP, &disp, NULL) < 0) {
 syslog(LOG_CRIT, "sigaction_main: %m");
 _exit(1);
}
```

Next, you make sure that the mask a newly spawned thread will inherit has also this signal blocked:

```
sigemptyset(&set);
sigaddset(&set, SIGHUP);
if ( (errno = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL)) != 0) {
 syslog(LOG_CRIT, "sigmask_main: %m");
 _exit(1);
}
```

At this point, you spawn all your threads that should not be interrupted by the signal (HUP). After this is all done, the main thread goes into dedicated mode of the signal waiting and handling:

```
for (; ;) {
 if ( (errno = sigwait(&set, &n)) != 0) {
  syslog(LOG_CRIT, "sigwait_main: %m");
  _exit(1);
 }
 if (n == SIGHUP) {
  /* do the errands */
 }
}
```

Comment: "*By default a signal is delivered to all threads ...*" This is missleading. Signal dispostion is on a per process base. Any of a process's thread may receive it, but it will be received only by one a process's threads.

Comment: @alk: that is exactly correct, thank you for noticing. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation & example helped me